# How to fix unhandled SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR in roslisp

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [roslisp tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslisp/Tutorials/BasicUsage).

I rosmake success and also run roscore. Then I tried to rosrun.

rosrun      roslisp_tutorials/bin/talker

```
 sam@/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/roslisp_support/roslisp_tutorials$ rosrun      roslisp_tutorials/bin/talker
 Usage: rosrun PACKAGE EXECUTABLE [ARGS]
   rosrun will locate PACKAGE and try to find
   an executable named EXECUTABLE in the PACKAGE tree.
   If it finds it, it will run it with ARGS.
 
 sam@/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/roslisp_support/roslisp_tutorials$
```

I guess it should be the following instruction,but also not works.

rosrun      roslisp_tutorials talker

```
 sam@/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/roslisp_support/roslisp_tutorials$ rosrun      roslisp_tutorials talker 
 unhandled SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD
                                                "initial thread"      RUNNING
                                                {1002AFC911}>:
   Couldn't load
        #P"/tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-roslisp-support-0.2.11/debian/ros-diamondbac     k-roslisp-support/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/roslisp_support/roslisp_tutorials/     bin/talker.lisp":
   file does not exist.
 
 0: (SB-DEBUG::MAP-BACKTRACE #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA #)      {1002B08B99}>)[:EXTERNAL]
 1: (BACKTRACE 128 #<SYNONYM-STREAM :SYMBOL SB-SYS:*STDERR*      {1000159B51}>)
 2: (SB-DEBUG::DEBUGGER-DISABLED-HOOK
     #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR "~@<Couldn't load ~S: file does not      exist.~@:>"
       {1002B03191}>
     #<unavailable argument>)
 3: (SB-DEBUG::RUN-HOOK
     *INVOKE-DEBUGGER-HOOK*
     #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR "~@<Couldn't load ~S: file does not      exist.~@:>"
       {1002B03191}>)
 4: (INVOKE-DEBUGGER
     #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR "~@<Couldn't load ~S: file does not      exist.~@:>"
       {1002B03191}>)
 5: (ERROR SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR)[:EXTERNAL]
 6: (LOAD
          #P"/tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-roslisp-support-0.2.11/debian/ros-diamondbac     k-roslisp-support/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/roslisp_support/roslisp_tutorials/     bin/talker.lisp")[:EXTERNAL]
 7: (SB-IMPL::PROCESS-EVAL/LOAD-OPTIONS
     ((:LOAD
       .      "/tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-roslisp-support-0.2.11/debian/ros-diamondback-     roslisp-support/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/roslisp_support/roslisp_tutorials/bi     n/talker.lisp")))
 8: (SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-INIT)
 9: ((LABELS SB-IMPL::RESTART-LISP))
 
 unhandled condition in --disable-debugger mode, quitting
 
 sam@/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/roslisp_support/roslisp_tutorials$
```

How to fixed it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11108/how-to-fix-unhandled-sb-int:simple-file-error-in-roslisp/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-09-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in roslisp script generation. I will have a look into it.

A quick fix would be to use roslisp_tutorials from source. If you already created the ~/cram-ros overlay as explained in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/2047/why-rosmake-cram_pl-says-cause-fatal-errors) question, you just need to do the following:

```
cd ~/cram-ros/workspace
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/roslisp_support/tags/diamondback/roslisp_tutorials roslisp_tutorials
rosmake roslisp_tutorials
```

Then, `rosrun roslisp_tutorials talker` should work.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-04-01**:
This overlay thing and source installed `roslisp_tutorials` (electric version) instead of bundled one do the work. Thank you!